# Adding activities to inflators

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am very new to `Xamarin` so i don't have the clearest idea on how inflators work.
How can i add functionality to a page that uses inflators to scroll between tabs? I.E. Where do i put the code for a button click event, when the button can be found in

`var root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment, container, false);` ?

This is my fragment page:

```
namespace OfficialApp{

public class ContentFragment: Fragment{

    private int position;
    public static ContentFragment NewInstance(int position)
    {
        var f = new ContentFragment();
        var b = new Bundle();
        b.PutInt("position", position);
        f.Arguments = b;
        return f;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        position = Arguments.GetInt("position");
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment, container, false);
        var editFile = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.editFile, container, false);

        if (position == 0)
        {
            return root;
        }
        else if (position == 1)
        {
            return editFile;
        }
        else
        ViewCompat.SetElevation(root, 50);
        return root ;
    }
}
```

}

Sorry if this is a vague or silly question but i honestly have not been able to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: "How can i add functionality to a page that uses inflators to scroll between tabs?", so you have a `TabLayout` in your main activity? I saw your code for `Fragment`, this is fragment used for show the page of one tab and you want to show different fragment when select different tabs on main activity?

Comment: The content fragment page is used as an index page for the fragments that show each page.My main activity uses a FragmentPageAdapter to allow the user to slide between tabs. What i'm not sure about is how to give each fragment its own activity so that for example pushing a button runs an on click event.

Comment: Still don't understand, the code "var root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment, container, false);" is to find the view for this fragment, if you have a button inside this view, you can find this button for example like this: `var btn = root.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn)`, then you can subscribe the click event of this view. What you mean to give a fragment its own activity? Here the activity means a subclass of `Activity`?

Comment: Where would you put var btn = root.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn) ?

Comment: before you return this view, or say "root".

Comment: All done for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What i'm not sure about is how to give each fragment its own activity so that for example pushing a button runs an on click event.

To find a control in the view which is inflated by `var root = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment, container, false);`, you can code for example like this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

    var btn = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btn);

    return view;
}
```